# ffmpeg , 2 network cards and multicast stream

Tags: networking, ffmpeg

my knowledge of networks are very poor!!, am a newbie!! ;-)

I have a small server streaming ffmpeg installed on nginx with 2 network interfaces

> p2p1 is used for WAN which provides http/ssh....
>
> p4p1  is used to receive multicast data from intranet.
>
> 192.168.0.1 is public network gateway.
>
> 192.168.1.1 is private network gateway (commented for not have internet exit this network)
>
> 239.0.0.*/24 is multicast address.

```
Linux distribution
3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID : Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release : 14.04
Codename : trusty
```

My network interfaces config

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# NET1
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1

# NET2
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
    ### gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Now my route table

```
root@srv:# route
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic Métric Ref    Uso Interfaz
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p2p1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
```

I'm using udpxy on port 4022 for converting IPTV multicast to unicast HTTP

```
udpxy -p 4022
```

I execute this

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "http://127.0.0.1:4022/rtp/239.0.0.76:8208" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-1:720 -r 25 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -crf 18 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2200k -c:a aac -ab 128k -strict -2 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:11111/rtmp/channel1;


ffmpeg version 2.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
http://127.0.0.1:4022/rtp/239.0.0.76:8208: Invalid data found when processing input
```

as I can solve this problem??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

210.0.0.0/24 are **not** multicast addresses.

The IPv4 multicast range is 224.0.0.0/4. See https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Multicast_address

It's quite possible that's the reason you're having issues.

**Edit**:

Also note the error message:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4022/rtp/239.0.0.76:8208: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I suppose that means there's a problem getting data from udpxy, so try running that verbose (udpxy -v -p 4022) and see what it says.

Comment: sorry the multicast range its 239.0.0.*/24 is multicast address.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the fixed ffmpeg command line.

Comment: What output does 'udpxy -v -p 4022' produce?